# Understanding this Collatz function code in R

Tags: r, function, math, functional-programming, collatz

I am new to the R programming language and want to sorry for this kind of easy question and have dealed the code of the collatz conjecture in R. Actually, I have fully understood the first two parts, but I dont the logic of the while loop in Part 3 and what is the need of n.total <- NULL. In addition, I dont understand the reason why it is combining the whole set as a vector in the last step with c(n.total,n). Thank you very much for your help!

```
Part 1:

is.even <- function(x){
  if(x%%2==0){
    print("TRUE")
  }else{
    print("FALSE")
  }
}

Part 2:

collatz <- function(n){
  if (is.even(n)) {
    n/2
  }else{
      3*n+1
    }
}

Part 3:

n <- 27
n.total <- NULL
while(n != 1){
  n <- collatz(n)
  n.total <- c(n.total,n)
}

n.total
```

---

## Edit

Credits must be given.
The code above comes from [this R-bloggers code](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/03/learning-r-the-collatz-conjecture/).

Comment: What's your specific issue? other than `is.even()` should return its result, not print it, which is breaking things. If you want a general code-review, post on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Good to see that you joined Stackoverflow. Greetings from your professor

Comment: @smci Don't post to [codereview.se] until the code works correctly, and you understand how it works.

Comment: @Teepeemm, ok, then where should OP post this sort of thing?

Comment: @smci "Explain this entire thing to me" probably doesn't belong anywhere on StackExchange.  "Explain Part 3 to me" may belong here, although the obvious bug in Part 1 suggests OP doesn't truly understand that either.  In this specific case though, OP probably should go to their professor's office hours to ask for help.

Comment: @Teepeemm, that's true but not helpful, please specifically tell the OP what changes are needed and then where is the most appropriate site they can post their question? I think I wrote as good an answer as can be given to someone who doesn't understand the code and isn't willing to put in a few `print` statements and try to debug a little.

Answer (score 3):

```
collatz <- function(n, acc=c()) {
  if(n==1) return(c(acc, 1));
  collatz(ifelse(n%%2==0, n/2, 3*n +1), c(acc, n))}
```

collatz(5) will return: 5 16  8  4  2  1